# Save App file to default folder

Tags: android, file

Well, I tried to search in google and SO, but didn't find much mainly because I am not sure what should be my search word. So, if anybody thinks this question is too generic and should be searched first, please help me providing some useful link.

What I want is, to have two buttons in my App which should download sample.csv and sample.php (I want to attach this file inside my App) file and save it to user directory, preferably in "download" folder or somewhere user can access easily.

I found [this page by searching](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) but here they demonstrates saving File on Internal Storage in App's folder only. Now I am confused whether this App's folder is accessible by browsing or not (I can't find my app's folder in my Samsung Note 2).

Another question pops up in my mind is, whether I have to read those sample files and create new file to save, or I can simply put a link and download the sample files I provided (more like HTML link)? Or may be I can just upload those sample files in my web server as zipped and give a link to dload?

Apology for my long email, but I am confused where to start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access your app's internal directory. However, what you can do is to use InputOutputStream to copy your file from the internal directory to your desired folder, and then delete the file from the app's directory. Try searching for copying files and you'll find multiple links.

Comment: thanks, I got almost everything .. just one thing I am stuck at, how to save the file to a default location (like download folder) in the mobile. What should be the path to that folder? As per documentation, getFilesDir() returns a File representing an internal directory for your app.

Comment: You should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get access to your SD card. In case you need detailed explanation, please let me know and I'll edit my answer accordingly. Please mark the answer as correct when you're able to solve it.

Comment: thank you, I knew that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for external storage. However, my goal was to save file in internal storage (for those who doesn't have an SD card). However, after thorough reading, I got to know that it is not possible to save file in public folders of internal storage. Thanks anyway.